# Azure Media Services - Secure Asset

Tags: azure, assets, azure-media-services

I'm doing some tests with Azure Media Services. I would like to publish an asset, however it only asks for the start date / end date. There's no option to restrict the access to a particular IP address. What are the options to secure the access of an asset since it's using SAS tokens.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is option to restrict asset with IP address. The asset owner should keep SAS secret.
The Azure Media Service has IP access control on Streaming Endpoint, but not asset itself.

Comment: the streaming endpoint requires the CDN right? In this case, every person with the url could open and check my file, unless I'll restrict the access to the ipaddress of my server. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Some further clarifications. I assume that you are trying to publish an encoded Asset for streaming via HLS or DASH protocols, via the Azure Portal. As my colleague already responded, we do not offer IP-address restriction on an Asset by Asset basis. However, you can apply IP address restriction to the streaming endpoint, which will apply to all videos you publish.

The attached screenshot of the Portal shows how you would adjust this. To get to this page, click on the desired streaming endpoint, and then click on Settings.[Settings for the streaming endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juQVN.jpg)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. What I'm trying to do is save money and use the functionality of smooth streamming provided by Media Services. So what I was thinking: upload the asset in a middle quality to avoid encoding, and point the video player with a SAS token (generated to every user) to restrict access to the asset, but as you guys said, it`s not possible right?